# Where to download bcp command line package for SQL Server 2019?

Tags: sql-server-2019, bulkcopy

I have a Windows 10 machine where I would like to run bcp from powershell to perform bulk copy operations against SQL Server 2019. Which package do I install to get bcp support Windows 10?  Would rather not install full blown SQL server if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BCP comes with "Command Line Utilities" package. You need to install "ODBC driver" first. Sending you the links for download

[Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16#version-17) - [Direct Download Link](https://download.microsoft.com/download/6/f/f/6ffefc73-39ab-4cc0-bb7c-4093d64c2669/en-US/17.10.3.1/x64/msodbcsql.msi)

[Microsoft Command Line Utilities 15 for SQL Server (x64)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver16#download-and-install-sqlcmd) - [Direct Download Link](https://download.microsoft.com/download/a/a/4/aa47b3b0-9f67-441d-8b00-e74cd845ea9f/EN/x64/MsSqlCmdLnUtils.msi)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like someone was kind enough to make a Chocolatey package to distribute bcp.

Here is the [link](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/sqlserver-cmdlineutils) to the package.